# Sqoop with query clause

Tags: oracle, hive, hdfs, sqoop

I need to move some data from Oracle to Hive and I saw that Sqoop could be a useful tool.
The problem is that I need to process a query and insert the result in a table in the destination database.

Oracle function result --> HiveDB.myTable

I found this command:

> ```
> sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@******:1522/**
> --username myUsername --password pwd --query '...' 
> --hive-import --split-by "myID" --hive-table "hive-table" --hive-database "hive-database"
> ```

but I need to specify a `--target-dir` mandatory and I don't have write rights in HDFS.

This is true only if I use --query, because if I use `--table`, `--target-dir` is not required.

Anyone knows if there is a way to avoid that `"--target-dir"` property using a query?

Comment: You can't avoid using the target-dir for the query option. When you say you don't have the permissions to write in HDFS, that can't be true because in the table option if you choose to ignore the target-dir, SQOOP will still write to HDFS but under the default location. The default location is under /user/hive/warehouse/<hive database>/<hive table name>. Try this location as the target-dir. I am sure that data will be written there.

Comment: Another option is to use "--where" option, which does not require --target-dir. This option works if you import from a single table.

Comment: @Ramesh I tried to specify --target-dir /user/hive/warehouse/<hive database>/<hive table name>, but I can't read/write in the folder /user/hive/warehouse.

Comment: Can you add the SQOOP command you ran to the question please. The actual command, not the example you already gave. Also, can you post the exact error message you are getting.

Comment: Do you have access to Hive?

Comment: Thank you all, I resolved using a different target-dir location with all rights.

Answer (score 0):

Other than hive table, you can use hcatalog table, but you have to give the target-dir location.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have write access in HDFS in order to import data. Most of the times hdfs:///tmp/ directory will be having write access to all the users. Use that as your target directory and run your command .